# How to define a character object into multiple lines?

Tags: r

I am trying to define a character object in R and I need to put the characters into multiple lines. I have tried different ways such as cat(), writeLines, etc but none of them worked. cat() gave me the output I want but I could not capture the output with the format.

My goal is to get:

```
mmodel <- 

      'F1=1-5

       F2=6-10'
```

I tried to capture the output of cat():

(1)

> cat("F1=1-5","F2=6-10",sep='\n')
>
> F1=1-5
>
> F2=6-10

(2) then when I try to capture the output of cat(), the format (multiple lines) is gone:

> capture.output(cat("F1=1-5","F2=6-10",sep='\n'))
>
> "F1=1-5"  "F2=6-10"

My question is: how can I save the cat() output with the multiple line format? Or is there any other way to define the object I want? Thanks!

Comment: `x = paste("F1=1-5","F2=6-10",sep='\n')`? It's not clear if this is what you want since you inserted a blank line between the F1 and F2 ones.

Comment: Sorry it is not a blank line. I wanted to make it clearer so I added a blank line I guess. It is "(1st line)F1=1-5 (2nd line)F2=6-10". Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Generally, you should feel free to edit your question if you think you can make it clearer or need to elaborate. Looks to me like `paste` should work. You might also be interested in `sprintf`. Help files are available by typing `?paste` and `?sprintf` in the R console.

Comment: Or use a 1-column matrix?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies. I appreciate it. It turns out that sprintf() worked. mmodel <- sprintf("%s\n%s","F1=1-5","F2=6-10") I

Comment: Read `?cat`. `cat` always returns NULL. It is only used for side-effects. `print` would return a value and has parameter to control whether quotes appear on hte console output.